# How to find, list, or search resources across services (APIs) and projects in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-resource-manager

In Google Cloud Platform (GCP), you can use list APIs or commands to list resources in a given project for a given type in a given service, like BigQuery datasets or compute instances.

But how to find or search resources across types, services, or even projects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use search-all-resources to search all the resources across services (or APIs) and projects for a given organization, folder, or project.

To search all the resources in a project with number 123:

```
$ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=projects/123
```

To limit to only compute resources:

```
$ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=projects/123 --query="compute.googleapis.com"
```

To limit to only resources containing "foo" as a sub string:

```
$ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=projects/123 --query="*foo*"
```

To list all the projects within an organization 456:

```
$ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=organizations/456 --asset-types=cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/Project
```

To find all the BigQuery datasets containing "foo" as a sub string within an organization 456:

```
$ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=organizations/456 --query="bigquery datasets *foo*"
```

You can set the scope to a project, a folder or an organization.

To use the command, you must:

- Enable [Cloud Asset API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudasset.googleapis.com), and
- Have `cloudasset.assets.searchAllResources` permission upon the scope, which is included in these roles:

  - roles/cloudasset.viewer
  - roles/cloudasset.owner
  - roles/viewer
  - roles/editor
  - roles/owner

Documentation:

- More gcloud examples: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources-samples
- Guide: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources
- Searchable resource types: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types