# Google Cloud Resource Management Java Api Projects List

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-resource-manager

I'm finding a way to programatically list Google Cloud projects inside an organization. I'm trying to use a service account exported json credential to achieve such purpose in this way:

```
    // More info on the endpoint here:
    // https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list
    final CloudResourceManager cloudResourceManagerService = createCloudResourceManagerService();
    final CloudResourceManager.Projects.List listRequest = cloudResourceManagerService
        .projects()
        .list()
        .setFilter("labels.it-restoring:false name:IT-TEST-*");

    final ListProjectsResponse listResponse = listRequest.execute();

    if (listResponse.isEmpty()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("The API did not get any response"); // I never get past here
    }

    log.info("Listing projects returned: {}", listResponse);
```

The problem I find is that I always get an empty response. Even though I assigned the service account the role of owner. According to docs, I could use `roles/
resourcemanager.organizationAdmin` which I also set but with no luck. I create the CloudResourceManagement api object using `getApplicationDefault`.

However if I do `gcloud beta auth application-default login` which triggers an auth flow in the browser and authenticate with the user which is the owner of the organization this works and lists all the projects that I have.

Can anybody explain to me what I should do to store a proper credential which would emulate he user owner? I already set the service account with the Owner role which in theory gives virtually access to all resources and still no luck.

Comment: A good debugging tool is APIs Explorer. In this case, you'd need to be an owner too for it to use your credentials but... it's a good way to prove the underlying API. Alternatively you can use `gcloud projects list ---log-http`. First step would be, if you can, to try APIs Explorer with that filter to confirm you do get results

Comment: When you run the code locally and wish to use a service account, you will need to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/jwt.json`

Answer (score 1):

In order to list the projects on your organization, you need the permission `resourcemanager.projects.get`. Please find more information in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) The service account might have the owner role of **1** project, and not enought to list them all.

Comment: Oh, so that means that I'm the owner of one project but not owner of the whole organization? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: From [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_role_definitions) you can see that `roles/owner` is project-wise. The organization-wise roles start with `resourcemanager.--` [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to grant the account the `cloudasset.assets.searchAllResources` permission at org level by using one of the following roles:

- roles/cloudasset.viewer
- roles/cloudasset.owner
- roles/viewer
- roles/editor
- roles/owner

With this permission, you can list all the projects within an organization 456:

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources \
--asset-types="cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/Project"
--scope=organizations/456
```

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources

Related post: [How to find, list, or search resources across services (APIs) and projects in Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517563/how-to-find-list-or-search-resources-across-services-apis-and-projects-in-go/60517564#60517564)