# How to list all projects inside GCP organization using Resource Manager API?

Tags: api, http, google-cloud-platform, access-token, google-cloud-resource-manager

I am trying to list all projects I have in GCP by using the [`projects.list`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) method from the Resource Manager API but I cannot figure out what access token to be used.

Let's say I have three projects:

- `My Project 44572`
- `Testing`
- `My First Project`

And when I use the `projects.list` method it should give me the output as this:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "My Project 44572", 
      "parent": {
        "type": "organization", 
        "id": "ORG_ID"
      }, 
      "projectId": "PROJECT_ID", 
      "projectNumber": "PROJECT_NUMBER", 
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE", 
      "createTime": "2020-06-15T08:38:04.712Z"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Testing ", 
      "parent": {
        "type": "organization", 
        "id": "ORG_ID"
      }, 
      "projectId": "PROJECT_ID", 
      "projectNumber": "PROJECT_NUMBER", 
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE", 
      "createTime": "2020-06-15T08:35:59.480Z"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "My First Project", 
      "parent": {
        "type": "organization", 
        "id": "ORG_ID"
      }, 
      "projectId": "PROJECT_ID", 
      "projectNumber": "PROJECT_NUMBER", 
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE", 
      "createTime": "2020-06-15T08:33:23.859Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

But if I am using the Access Token which I got by using service account of `My Project 44572` I am getting the following output:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "My Project 44572", 
      "parent": {
        "type": "organization", 
        "id": "ORG_ID"
      }, 
      "projectId": "PROJECT_ID", 
      "projectNumber": "PROJECT_NUMBER", 
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE", 
      "createTime": "2020-06-15T08:38:04.712Z"
    }
]
}
```

So, what access token I should use so that I would get all projects under my organization?

[image: Postman console]

Comment: I don't understand your question: What's the relation between your organisation's project and Google Cloud Storage. A bucket belong to only one project and accound (service account that belong ot another project) can have access to the bucket. So, can you clarify what you want? Maybe with a dummy example of what you expect?

Comment: I agree with Guillaume. I do not understand the Cloud Storage usage in your issue. Please elaborate a bit more so we can help you with this.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  i had updated the question now with an example. Please check now and let me know if it helps

Comment: @OqueliA.Martinez Please check now

Comment: Which request are you performing? Do you have piece of code or gcloud command? Do you have an organisationID or folderID?

Comment: I am performing GET Request on https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects end point and i had updated the question with detailed information about the request

Answer (score 2):

The projects.list method requires the permission `resourcemanager.projects.get`. You can grant the account any role containing the permission at org level to achieve your goal, e.g.,    -

- roles/viewer
- roles/editor
- roles/owner

Alternatively, you can use the resources.searchAll method which requires the `cloudasset.assets.searchAllResources` permission. You can grant the account any role with this permission at org level:

- roles/cloudasset.viewer
- roles/cloudasset.owner
- roles/viewer
- roles/editor
- roles/owner

To list all the projects within an organization 456:

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources \
--asset-types="cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/Project"
--scope=organizations/456
```

Documentation:

- https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources
- https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/resources/searchAll

Related post:

- [How to find, list, or search resources across services (APIs) and projects in Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517563/how-to-find-list-or-search-resources-across-services-apis-and-projects-in-go/60517564#60517564)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by assigning the service account of "My Project 44572" Owner role at Organization level and now when i use the access token generated by this service account it would list all the projects in my organization