# Is there any we we could search resources in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to search service which can query the gcp resources configuration details, Just similar to Azure Resource Graph Query & AWS Config Query

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `cloudasset.assets.searchAllResources` permission upon an organization, a folder or a project, you can list all the resources under the org using search-all-resources:

```
$ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=organizations/123
$ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=folders/456
$ gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=projects/789
```

More details can be found in another post:
[How to find, list, or search resources across services (APIs) and projects in Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517563/how-to-find-list-or-search-resources-across-services-apis-and-projects-in-go)