# How do I list all resources in a particular google cloud project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I dont see an easy way of listing the resources in a google cloud project from the console. For those familiar with Azure, I can easily navigate over to the resource group and it will displays all the resources within it. I cannot appear to do the same in google cloud.

Comment: Google Cloud has a similar feature [Asset Inventory](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/asset-inventory/resources) but the Google Cloud GUI displays resources by (I think) SKU which means a large amount of detail is displayed. The weakness is that all resources are not included. For me, that is primarily useful if I am auditing a project. Azure provides details at a higher level (fewer details). See Fariya's answer for more information. The Google Cloud benefit is that you can export the details (CSV) for use in a spreadsheet or similar type of app.

Comment: @user1074593 You can also refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517563) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Google Asset inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview) feature to list all the resources in your project.

> To search all resources using the [console](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources#console), complete the following
> steps.
>
> 1. Go to the Asset Inventory page in the Google Cloud console.
> 2. To set the scope of your search, open the Projects list box in the menu bar, and then select the organization, folder, or project to
>    query.
> 3. Select the Resource tab.
> 4. To search resources, enter the query text in the Filter bar. Select the text box, and then a list of searchable fields display. Resource
>    search supports multiple fields.
> 5. Search results can also be filtered by the pre-defined Asset type, Project, and Location filters in the Filter results pane.

However, all the resources aren't supported. You can find the full list of supported asset type [here](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types).