# How to remove GCP resources that use the API regional quota?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, quota

When I run a terraform on GCP I get the error:

> Error: googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB": request requires '100.0' and is short '100.0'. project has a quota of '500.0' with '0.0' available.

Indeed, I can check than the quota in full, but I do not see any disks in in Compute Engine.[image]

Is there a way to remove all the resources that use this quota or do you know where I can with these resources?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Google Cloud Console GUI will show you the resources you have. For example, the first item in your screenshot is `Persistent Disk SSD`. Go to the disk section and review. You can also put the word `DISK` in the GUI search bar.

Comment: I cannot see any resources in neither `Compute Engine > Disks` nor `Kubernetes Engine > Storage`, though quota is still 100% ://

Comment: Do you have the correct IAM roles to view resources? Edit your question with details after reading this [guide](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76676121/8016720) for another method to view resources.